# How was I able to earn more reputation after being awarded Mortarboard?

Tags: support, stackexchange-2.0, daily-reputation-badges

I was awarded the Mortarboard badge about an hour ago on the Gaming StackExchange site.

[mortarboard awarded screenshot http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/9623/mortarboard.png](http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/9623/mortarboard.png)

A little while later, I got an upvote (on an answer) that gave me 5 reputation, and another upvote for 0 reputation. So I was not yet at the reputation cap when I was given the mortarboard badge.

[later upvotes screenshot http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/4826/upvotes.png](http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/4826/upvotes.png)

Is this a bug or is the mortarboard calculated differently than I how I think it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mortarboard badge is awarded when you reach 200 rep in a day, not when you hit the cap (if I remember previous discussions correctly).

You could look at your reputation report to be sure. The URL should be something like https://gaming.stackexchange.com/reputation.

Comment: Ah, I see. I did reach 217 reputation then. I thought accepted answers were not counted towards the reputation limit only if they were accepted after the cap had been reached? Has this changed? (Then I guess the other 2 reputation points would also be immune, which was me accepting an answer?)

Comment: @Brandon: Yes, the rules were changed a month or two back (when there was a global rep recalc). Accepting/accepted answers and bounties are now completely immune.